# Why gcc can't find the right version of Gtk and Gdk?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, ubuntu-11.10

Hello I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. I tried to compile a simple Gtk example in eclipse... The result is that it says gtk is missing. I looked in usr/include and there is both gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0. 
So in the include I wrote

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>
```

but now it complains that it can't find gdk.h.... it is the gtk-3.0 tree! why it can't find it? I even tried to symlink gtk to gtk-3.0 dir with no result...

Comment: The simple way is to have your `Makefile` and use `pkg-config` inside. I have no idea what Eclipse is doing under the hoods, and you need to understand that before asking.

Comment: I'm not using a makefile and I'm not using pkg-config, how can I understand them, point me to some tutorial please.

Comment: When using `pkg-config` you should `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` without the `gtk-3.0/` prefix.

Answer (score 6):

`#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>` should just be `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`

Then, you're supposed to use the output of the command:

```
 pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags
```

As the compiler flags when you compile your program, and

```
 pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs
```

When you link your program.

See the "Compiling GTK+ Applications" in the [GTK documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/)